# Publish artifacts while build in progress in ANT, teamcity

Tags: build-automation, teamcity, artifacts

Any ideas on how to publish teamcity artifacts while build is in progress using ANT. I use ANT as build runner in teamcity.
[Build interaction](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD4/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity)
It says use it as ##teamcity[publishArtifacts '']. Any ideas on how it works in ANT scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artifact can be publish at run time by following command:

```
 <echo message="##teamcity[publishArtifacts '${checkOutDir}/package/']"/>
```

${checkOutDir}/package/ is the folder which the required artifacts to be published to teamcity.